# Django/Wagtail trying to create generic child classes

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I'm working on a Django/Wagtail app and I'm trying to create generic, reusable components in my models. I'm trying to follow the way the built-in Image classes work since they can be attached to any other object type.
However I keep getting an error:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x7f78b26ad8c8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/.../runtime/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Django-1.8.14-py3.4.egg/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 229, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/.../runtime/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Django-1.8.14-py3.4.egg/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 114, in inner_run
    self.validate(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/.../runtime/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Django-1.8.14-py3.4.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 469, in validate
    return self.check(app_configs=app_configs, display_num_errors=display_num_errors)
  File "/.../runtime/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Django-1.8.14-py3.4.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 482, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/.../runtime/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Django-1.8.14-py3.4.egg/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/.../runtime/lib/python3.4/site-packages/wagtail/wagtailadmin/checks.py", line 64, in get_form_class_check
    edit_handler = cls.get_edit_handler()
  File "/.../runtime/lib/python3.4/site-packages/wagtail/utils/decorators.py", line 55, in __call__
    return self.value
  File "/.../runtime/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Django-1.8.14-py3.4.egg/django/utils/functional.py", line 59, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/.../runtime/lib/python3.4/site-packages/wagtail/utils/decorators.py", line 51, in value
    return self.fn(self.cls)
  File "/.../runtime/lib/python3.4/site-packages/wagtail/wagtailadmin/edit_handlers.py", line 824, in get_edit_handler
    return EditHandler.bind_to_model(cls)
  File "/.../runtime/lib/python3.4/site-packages/wagtail/wagtailadmin/edit_handlers.py", line 334, in bind_to_model
    'children': [child.bind_to_model(model) for child in self.children],
  File "/.../runtime/lib/python3.4/site-packages/wagtail/wagtailadmin/edit_handlers.py", line 334, in <listcomp>
    'children': [child.bind_to_model(model) for child in self.children],
  File "/.../runtime/lib/python3.4/site-packages/wagtail/wagtailadmin/edit_handlers.py", line 354, in bind_to_model
    'children': [child.bind_to_model(model) for child in self.children],
  File "/.../runtime/lib/python3.4/site-packages/wagtail/wagtailadmin/edit_handlers.py", line 354, in <listcomp>
    'children': [child.bind_to_model(model) for child in self.children],
  File "/.../runtime/lib/python3.4/site-packages/wagtail/wagtailadmin/edit_handlers.py", line 754, in bind_to_model
    related = getattr(model, self.relation_name).related
AttributeError: 'ReverseSingleRelatedObjectDescriptor' object has no attribute 'related'
```

Here is my code for the models:

```
class DownloadObject(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = RichTextField(blank=True)
    download_link = models.URLField()

    cover_image = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtailimages.Image',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name='+'
    )

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Downloads(DownloadObject):
    admin_form_fields = (
        'cover_image',
        'title',
        'description',
        'download_link',
    )

class Container(Page):
    body = RichTextField(blank=True)

    downloads = models.ForeignKey(
        'Downloads',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name='+'
    )

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('body', classname="full"),
        InlinePanel('downloads', label="downloads"),
    ]
```

What I'm trying to do is make it so the Downloads object is accessible to not only the Container model but other models as well.

Comment: Please post the full stack trace, and the code that triggers the error.

Comment: I suspect the `downloads` foreign key on Container is incorrect - it implies that you have a model called Downloads (not Download), and that each Container can only have one Downloads (but one Downloads can have multiple Containers). It's hard to tell without the full error stack trace or a description of what the models are supposed to do, though.

Comment: Ok I tried correcting the Download(s) issue but I'm getting the same error. Added the stack trace to the question.